# sed: Multiple -e or while loop?

Tags: sed

I have a CSV file with tuples of values where I need to change occurrences of one into another in a different (large) file.

Thus far, I have done a while read line [...] < foo.csv, essentially running sed one time for each line in the CSV file.

This takes quite some amount of time, so I wondered if I should change the while loop to construct a very long string of multiple -e statements, and then running that with eval.

I could try, obviously, but if someone can tell me if sed will just, essentially, do the same that I have done thus far, namely running through the file for each -e statement, meaning that no performance gain is to be had, then I don't think I shall bother.

Edit after comments:

Basically, I do the following:

```
while read line
do
  old_user=echo $line | cut -d \; -f 2|tr -d \"
  new_user=echo $line | cut -d \; -f 4|tr -d \"

  if [ "$old_user" != "$new_user" ]
  then
    sed -i -e "s/^(.*ri:username=\")$old_user(\".*)$/\1$new_user\2/g" confluence/entities_converted.xml
  fi
done < usernames.csv
```

If you notice that it's an XML file, the reason is that there are a number of instances where XML parsing and rewriting is cumbersome, hence `sed`. I just wonder if, instead of running `sed` multiple times, I should construct multiple `-e` arguments to `sed`.

`usernames.csv` looks like

```
    "Full name";"Username";"Email";"New username"
    "Sune Mølgaard";"sune.molgaard";"foo@bar.baz";"smo"
```

There may be any number of lines along the way of the second line, hence the looping. I am aware that the first line probably won't match, but that is insignificant.

Comment: Please, tell us more about the change. How exactly do you want to change the input?

Comment: do not reply in comment, you should edit your post.

Comment: Could you also post a sample of the input?

Comment: multiple `-e`, not `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to eval or construct multiple -e's. Sed can read its "program" from a file or pipe which you can in fact generate in sed, too:

```
cut -f2,4 -d\; usernames.csv \
    | sed -e 's/^/s%ri:username=/' -e 's/;/%ri:username=/' -e 's/$/%/' \
    | sed -i~ -f- confluence/entities_converted.xml
```

To check the generated program, remove the last line.

If you want to skip the lines where no change is needed (might speed it up), remove them by inserting `grep` between the seds:

```
   | grep -v '"\(.*\)".*"\1"' \
```

Comment: Hmmm, first two lines seem to generate lines a la `s%ri:username="sune.molgaard"%ri:username="smo"%`

Is that some other `sed` syntax that I don't know of, as opposed to `s/foo/bar/`?

Comment: clever move, keeping quotes !!  ( s%foo%bar% is equivalent to s/foo/bar/ or syfooybary )

Comment: @SuneMølgaard: You can use any character with substitution, not just `/`. Here, it avoids backslashing.

Comment: Almost 8x times faster than my naïve approach - thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

you sould use awk to parse usernames.csv (where field 2 and 4 are different), and generate sed file.

```
 tr -d \" username.csv |
 awk -F\; '$2 != $4 { printf "s/^(.*ri:username=%c)%s(%c.*)$/\\1%s\\2/g\n",34,$2,34,$4 ; }' |
 sed -i -f - confluence/entities_converted.xml
```

some trick

- use printf "..%c..",34 to generate quotes.
- you can skip the sed line in debug part to make sure all sed instructions are properly generated.
- do you need `/g` in substitution ?

on my test file

```
;foo;;foo;;
;fubar;;mr X;;
;bar;;bistro;;
    "Full name";"Username";"Email";"New username"
    "Sune Mølgaard";"sune.molgaard";"foo@bar.baz";"smo"
```

this generate

```
s/^(.*ri:username=")fubar(".*)$/\1mr X\2/g
s/^(.*ri:username=")bar(".*)$/\1bistro\2/g
s/^(.*ri:username=")Username(".*)$/\1New username\2/g
s/^(.*ri:username=")sune.molgaard(".*)$/\1smo\2/g
```

don't bother to remove Username's line, if not found, no substitute.

Comment: For some reason, I had to change `tr -d \" usernames.csv` to `cat usernames.csv | tr -d \"`, but then it seems to generate correct lines to pipe further into `sed` - will time a run shortly to see if it improves speed - thank you!

Also, I do believe that I need `/g`, since multiple occurrences a possible, or does `/g` just pertain to multiple occrrences *per line*?

Comment: I went with choroba's approach, but thank you very much!